# How to count and create a sum of those counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help constructing my query to do a count of system type id's.

Example:

```
SystemTypeID  Description           Acronym
1             System1 description   ABC
2             System2 description   DEF
3             System3 description   XYZ
```

I'm looking to construct something like this:

```
Count  SystemTypeID  Description           Acronym
21     1             System1 description   ABC
100    2             System2 description   DEF
67     3             System3 description   XYZ
```

So far, I know how to do a distinct, but I'm looking to count the number of occureneces for the SystemTypeID and then group it:

```
select distinct(a.SystemTypeID), 
       b.Description, 
       b.Acronym
from operations.Systems a,
     operations.SystemTypes b  
where a.SystemTypeID=b.SystemTypeID 
order by a.SystemType_ID;
```

Comment: You are looking for `group by` and `count(*)` -- two fundamental elements of the SQL language.  If you are going to use the language, you should learn it.

Comment: Does the phrase, "create a sum of those counts" indicate a misleadling subject line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `DISTINCT`, what you need is `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COUNT(a.SystemTypeID) AS `Count`, 
       a.SystemTypeID,
       b.Description, 
       b.Acronym
FROM operations.Systems a,
     operations.SystemTypes b  
WHERE a.SystemTypeID = b.SystemTypeID
GROUP BY a.SystemTypeID,
       b.Description, 
       b.Acronym
ORDER BY a.SystemType_ID;
```

Comment: Got it. I didn't realize you can count the column and select it again.